# Ornstein-Ulhenbeck like semigroup for the orthogonal group with a hypercontractive inequality

Tags: pr.probability, convex-geometry, measure-concentration, heat-equation, semigroups-of-operators

I am looking for an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck like semigroup $P_t$ and associated generator $\mathcal{L}$ on $G = \operatorname{SO}(n)$ or $\operatorname{O}(n)$ that has a hypercontractive inequality with a decent rate. For example, for the Gaussian measure on $G = \mathbb{R}^n$, the standard OU semigroup acts on $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

$$
P_t f(x) = E[ f( e^{- t} x + \sqrt{1 - e^{-2 t}} Z ]
$$

where $Z$ is a standard iid Gaussian vector and $E$ is the associated expectation operator. This is the Mehler formula.

Nelson's hypercontractive inequality says that for $p > 1$, let $q(t) = 1 + (p-1) e^{2t}$, then

$$
\left\| P_t f \right\|_{q(t)} \leq \left\| f \right\|_{p} \quad t > 0
$$

$\operatorname{SO}(n)$ or $\operatorname{O}(n)$ with Haar measure satisfy the Bakry-Emery curvature condition as manifolds and hence have Log-Sobolev inequalities. I am looking for an OU like semigroup and generator that satisfies a hypercontractive inequality. Ideally,

1. the generator should be simple in local matrix coordinates (i.e., $Q = \{Q_{ij}\}_{i,j=1}^n \in \operatorname{O}(n)$), or the semigroup should have a Mehler-like formula.
2. The hypercontrative inequality should have a rate $q(t) = 1 + (p-1)e^{\rho t}$, $\rho$ such that $\rho \geq O(1)$ for all $n$.

If there are similar results on the Symmetric group $S_n$, those might work for me as well. I am also open to discrete-time Markov chains on $\operatorname{O}(n)$.

I can see that there are lots of general results, but I'm hoping an expert can quickly point me to some standard reference. I have seen Elizabeth Meckes' wonderful notes, but it doesn't talk about the hypercontractive inequality. All we know is that if you have some nice semigroup, then by Gross' theorem, it satisfies a hypercontractive inequality.